# Cefsharp setup prerequisites

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I need to redistribute Winforms application that uses CefSharp browser.
I read a few post regarding the subject but I didn't found what i l was looking for. I am using Visual studio installer setup wizard. 
When i go to prerequisites in setup properties i get this list of prerequisites:

[image]

So my question is:
Which of these should I check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

CefSharp requires the Microsoft VC++ Runtime, as listed in [their FAQ page](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions):

```
+------------------+--------------+--------------+
| CefSharp Version | VC++ Version | .Net Version |
+------------------+--------------+--------------+
| 64.0.0 and above |         2015 |        4.5.2 |
| 51.0.0 to 63.0.0 |         2013 |        4.5.2 |
| 45.0.0 to 49.0.0 |         2013 |        4.0.0 |
| 43.0.0 and below |         2012 |        4.0.0 |
+------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

So, you should check the appropriate version of the .Net Framework. Also you should check or distribute the correct version of the Microsoft VC++ Runtime, or else you see errors similar to:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies

The FAQ page describes a few ways to incorporate the Microsoft VC++ Runtime into your distribution.